# How to add close to minimize to header to Gridster.js widgets

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, gridster

I'm trying to add close and minimize icons (buttons) like  to the stock gridster.js widget [image: Proposed Gridster.js widget] .

There's an example on their site: http://gridster.net/demos/custom-drag-handle  but its just a simple way to create a background color for the header  and doesn't illustrate how you can atach buttons (handles) for close and minimize..  any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked a while ago, but if you're still looking for an answer, like me, this fiddle should be able to give you an idea:

**[JSFIDDLE](http://%20jsfiddle.net/RzLf5/7/)**

It's not mine, just found it.

edit: I've came up with a simple solution myself.

You can add an header to the widget you want to create and put a button inside of this.
E.G.:

```
<li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="8" data-sizey="4">
      <header>
        <button class="pure-button" id="close-widget-button" style="font-size: 50%; float: right;">
            <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
        </button>
      </header>
      <iframe id="myframe" src="web/widgets/basiclinewidget2.html" width="600" height="300" frameborder="0">
      </iframe>
  </li>
```

The actual widget in this example is fetched from a server and loaded in an iframe.
I also use [pure](http://purecss.io/buttons/) buttons with a [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) icon in this example. Moreover, I make the button 'float' to the right and reduced its size. 
You can add operations (like closing or resizing) to your button with javascript as you would normally.